# How to make a drop down menu with images?

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I want to create a drop down menu with images (which reference to the sub menu.so how to create this? i am bit new to web designing.

i want to create menu like [Blossomboxjewelry](http://www.blossomboxjewelry.com/)

i have so far tried this [Dropdownmenu](http://www.siyatechnologies.com/dropmenu/) but i want to open image in div like above link.

Comment: can you share the code that you have tried already?

Comment: i added a link above which i have tried.

Comment: Is there a reason you chose to [delete your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180045/how-to-make-a-drop-down-menu-with-images) and ask a new one? Editing, and improving, that question would have bumped it back to the front page. (And thank you Google, I *knew* I'd read this question before...). Can I suggest that you explain what difficulties you're having? Where are you stuck? What help do you need?

Comment: sorry, i ll take care next time.

Comment: @Vivek try changing you layout, look carefully another site's css  and compare yours.

Comment: i cant see because rigth click is not allowed there.

Comment: @VivekParikh: As a web developer you should easily be able to circumvent those ridiculous scripts. Tip: Disable JavaScript or configure your browser to block rightclick events or use the "view source" option in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is probably too long to give you on here, but [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/) is probably able to help you out

Comment: i want a little change to make this menu like above given link.

Comment: Well its quite a task to try to hash open the code you already have (which you haven't provided) and amend it to include the images, wouldn't it make more sense just to follow their method of making the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/getting-started/